# wordpress: Conditionally run javascript and load image for post pages

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a javascript curl effect in place which loads an image and javascript file for the curl effect. But I want to appear in the post pages only.
So I want to do:

```
if this is a postpage{
   load image;
   load javascript;}
```

What is the way to do this in wordpress with php?

Comment: if i use it in index.php it appears everywhere.So I need this conditional thing? no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add it only to posts pages and homepages and your plug ins are troubling you..you might want to try

```
<?php if (is_single()|| is_home() || is_page()){ ?>
    load image;
    load js;
<?php } ?>
```

if you want it for only posts and pages, try

```
<?php if (is_single()|| is_page()){ ?>
        load image;
        load js;
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

not entierly sure what your after, 
but you say you have the code ont he index.php page, 
again un-sure has to, how you have this setup,

but if its only to be shown on a post or page or a postpage? (single post), 
would be better to move your code into the header.php file? or have it only in the single.php file which means its only loaded when viewing a single post, 
in turn it wont be shown on any other pages, except the single (full post) page..

then using the likes

```
if( is_single() ){
 //then show - run your code?
}
```

?

Marty

Edit:

for both posts & pages then use

```
if( is_single() || is_page() ){
 //then show - run your code?
}
```

this will only show your code when its a single post OR within a page.

Comment: i want it for single post and page too. Only want to prevent it from appearing on home page and some pop up contact form plug ins